# using for loop only diaplays the last image

Tags: arrays, for-loop, javafx

I wrote some code like the following trying to display an array of 20 images but only got the last image displayed. I am in great confusion and looking forward to your help!

```
 String []img={"a.png","b.png","c.png"...20 more};
 for(int x=0;x<20;x++)
    {
        images[x]=new Image(img[x]);
        views[x]=new ImageView(images[x]);


//put the images in the buttons on GridPane
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){//row
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){//column
                buttons[5*i+j]=new Button();
                buttons[5*i+j].setGraphic(new ImageView(images[x]));
                gridPane.add(buttons[5*i+j], j, i);
                buttons[5*i+j].setPrefHeight(120);
                buttons[5*i+j].setPrefWidth(120);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nested all three loops inside each other. So, in pseudo-code:

```
for each of the 20 images:
    for each row:
        for each column:
            create a button showing the image in the row/column
```

or, equivalently:

```
for each of the 20 images:
    for each cell:
        create a button showing the image in the cell
```

So on the first iteration of the outermost loop, you fill the grid with buttons, all showing the first image. On the second iteration of the outermost loop, you fill the grid with buttons, each showing the second image. And so on.

So each cell in the grid has 20 buttons: all of them will be placed on top of each other, and only the last one added will be visible.

You only want one button in each cell:

```
String[] img = {"a.png","b.png","c.png" /*...20 in totalv*/};

for(int x = 0 ; x < 20 ; x++) {
    images[x]=new Image(img[x]);
    views[x]=new ImageView(images[x]);
}

//put the images in the buttons on GridPane
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {  //row
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++ ) {    //column
        int index = 5 * i + j 
        buttons[index]=new Button();
        buttons[index].setGraphic(views[index]);
        gridPane.add(buttons[index], j, i);
        buttons[index].setPrefHeight(120);
        buttons[index].setPrefWidth(120);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're so cooool!!